# "Not" symbol or operator in maven <include> tag

Tags: maven, configuration, include, maven-plugin

Is there such thing as a not operator in maven that can be used in configuration  tag?
We have ** and * to denote all but do we have something to denote "not" to say

> Include all that is not ________

example:

```
<include>/folder/**/(not)filename.*</include>
```

`<exclude>` is tedious to use when you have many files to exclude.

I am using Maven-Jar-Plugin.

Comment: In relationship with which plugin? Or where? Can you give a more detailed example what the problem is?

Comment: This can be done using regular expressions, for the plugins that support it. But what specific `<include>` are we talking about here?

Comment: Why not removing the folders from src/main/java ?

Comment: Instead of wanting to `<include>` "not something", why not `<exclude>` it instead? Can you post what you're trying to match? Maybe there's another way.